# odoo datamigration: Enter one product on several pricelists via odoorpc on python

Tags: python, odoo, erp, odoo-rpc

I am working on a python import-script to import data from an xls sheet to odooErp.
In the script, there is information like "name", "if it is a bom list" and (important) for "prices" for different pricelists (in this case p1-p4).

I am using the following versions: 
Odoo: Community v.12
python: v. 3.7.6
odoorpc: 0.7.0

My script is already able to find the products in the odoodb, take some of the xls-data and writes it to the product in the odoodb. 
These are field like name, price (which is the standard price), type, etc. (standard rpc calls)
But I was not able to manage writing the product to a pricelist or to assign a pricelist to the product. 
I did not found any documentation about this step on how to manage the syntax for solving this.
So I tried to do this:

```html
PricelistModel = odoo.env['product.pricelist']
  pricelist = PricelistModel.search([('name', '=', 'p1')], limit=1)
  if pricelist:
      p = PricelistModel.browse(pricelist)
      
      item = {
          'applied_on': '1_product',
          'product_tmpl_id': product['id'], #<-- this is int also tried string
          'compute_price': 'fixed',
          'fixed_price': float(row[3]) #<--- this is int also tried string
      }

      p.write({
          'item_ids':
              item 
      })
```

Unfortunately even with no errors shown and receiving a "True" from the function this call is not successful and is doing nothing.

Now my questions are:

- I want to do more with that odoorpc, but the documentation is way to short and not even scratching the surface of all the possibilities I could imagine to do. -> is there a way to print out the answer why odoo isn't writing to the DB so I could teach myself how to "talk" with odoo?
- Does anyone know a solution to get this problem solved?

Cheers and thank you very much for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
PricelistModel = odoo.env['product.pricelist']
pricelist = PricelistModel.search([('name', '=', 'p1')], limit=1)
if pricelist:
    item = {
        'applied_on': '1_product',
        'product_tmpl_id': product['id'], #<-- this is int also tried string
        'compute_price': 'fixed',
        'fixed_price': float(row[3]) #<--- this is int also tried string
    }

    # I assume the 'item' is a correct dictionary and the 'item_ids' is a One2many field, so you need an One2many special command

    p.write({
        'item_ids': [(0, False, item)] 
    })
```

you can read https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#create-update as reference for One2many special command